# MonoDevelop and Unity, namespaces delegates showing up in intellisense?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, intellisense

In MonoDevelop I have noticed that any delegate declared in a namespace (and not within a class definition) seem to show up in intellisense in classes that do not import that namespace.

My example code looks like this:

FunDelegates.cs:

```
namespace mydelegates
{
    internal delegate void FunnyDelegate();
}
```

Test.cs:

```
namespace some.other.name.space
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Test ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now if I place the cursor in the Test constructor and type "Fu", code hinting gives me "FunnyDelegates".

My question is:

Is this correct behaviour, and am I misunderstanding something, or is MonoDevelops intellisense wrong?

Comment: And that only happens for delegates? Not for classes in other namespaces? What happens when you select that delegate type via intellisense? Does it add the namespace automatically or does it add a using directive?

Comment: It looks like it's only the delegates that show up. If I select the delegate via intellisense the namespace is not imported (does MonoDevelop ever autoimport namespaces? If yes, pleeeease tell me how). If I actually try to use the delegate in some code without the using statement, I get a compiler error asking if im missing a using directive.

Comment: Weird. If delegates are the only thing where that happens, maybe that's a question for MonoDevelop's developers. (Don't know about autoimport, i only use Visual Studio)